# Wake iPhone without asking for the passcode

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, passcode

Is it possible to keep iPhone unlocked after pressing the power button? When I make a route with Apple Maps and press the power button, the screen gets turned off. After pressing the power button again, the iPhone doesn't ask for a passcode. Is it possible to make it in Xcode?

Comment: I can’t reproduce. Can you elaborate on the steps to reproduce?

Comment: Go to Maps > Type any city in the search bar > Press the blue car button > Press the green "GO" button
After that, if you turn off the phone screen and then turn it back on, the phone won't ask for a passcode.

Comment: As of iOS 15.6.1, this no longer works. I performed your steps. The "turn it back on" step shows the map.app with directions. But if you do not accidentally authenticate, you will need to enter a passcode.